# MSSQL, SP_EXECUTESQL and javax.persistence.EntityManager

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jdbc

Have a JavaEE application that is being migrated from Oracle to SQL Server 2016. 
 Uses Java 1.7, jboss 4.2.3.GA and hibernate 3.2.4.sp1.

The application uses the javax EntityManager for DB access and so queries look like this:

```
    List<ServiceProvider> providers = entityManager
            .createQuery("FROM ServiceProvider sp order by sp.id")
            .setMaxResults(spCount)
            .getResultList();
```

But a SQL Trace shows the query being wrapped in `exec sp_executesql`.

For example the above becomes `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (50) ....'`

If I trace a query coming from say an SSRS report, it is not wrapped in the `sp_executesql`.

What is responsible for this transformation?

** edited to a single focused question.

Comment: This is simply how the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver works. If you want to know the details, I suggest you ask Microsoft, eg on https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It seems to be hibernate, if I run the same query with the same driver via jMeter, it doesn't get wrapped in sp_executesql.

Comment: That is probably the difference between executing a 'normal' statement and a prepared statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel no doubt. At any rate, jMeter shows me better performance with and without sp_executesql, so looking at hibernate config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarkRotteveel mentioned in his comment, it seems the MS JDBC driver uses `sp_executesql` when executing a prepared statement. Once we fixed our missing `pool-size` and `prepared-statement-cache-size` options we see no difference between Oracle 12g and SQL Server 2016 so I don't believe there is a performance hit by using `sp_executesql` or if there it, it is *very* minimal.

```
    <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>220</max-pool-size>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
```

Interestingly enough, Hibernate executes fewer queries when targeting MSSQL than Oracle. The query in my original post results in 12 Oracle queries vs 10 in MSSQL.

Comment: If anyone has more info on the mssql-jdbc driver's use of sp_executesql I'd be happy to switch the accepted answer.